# An array initializer of length '16' is expected

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to create SBOX for the AES algorithm, so i want to create a matrix of 16 row and 16 columns.

I created a 2d array of [16, 16], but i keep getting an error about an initializer of length 16 is needed, what is wrong with my code?

```
int[,] SBox = new int[16, 16] 
            {
            //0     1    2      3     4    5     6     7      8    9     A      B    C     D     E     F
            {0x63}, {0x7c}, {0x77}, {0x7b}, {0xf2}, {0x6b}, {0x6f}, {0xc5}, {0x30}, {0x01}, {0x67}, {0x2b}, {0xfe}, {0xd7}, {0xab}, {0x76} , //0
            {0xca}, {0x82}, {0xc9}, {0x7d}, {0xfa}, {0x59}, {0x47}, {0xf0}, {0xad}, {0xd4}, {0xa2}, {0xaf}, {0x9c}, {0xa4}, {0x72}, {0xc0}, //1
            {0xb7}, {0xfd}, {0x93}, {0x26}, {0x36}, {0x3f}, {0xf7}, {0xcc}, {0x34}, {0xa5}, {0xe5}, {0xf1}, {0x71}, {0xd8}, {0x31}, {0x15}, //2
            {0x04}, {0xc7}, {0x23}, {0xc3}, {0x18}, {0x96}, {0x05}, {0x9a}, {0x07}, {0x12}, {0x80}, {0xe2}, {0xeb}, {0x27}, {0xb2}, {0x75}, //3
            {0x09}, {0x83}, {0x2c}, {0x1a}, {0x1b}, {0x6e}, {0x5a}, {0xa0}, {0x52}, {0x3b}, {0xd6}, {0xb3}, {0x29}, {0xe3}, {0x2f}, {0x84}, //4
            {0x53}, {0xd1}, {0x00}, {0xed}, {0x20}, {0xfc}, {0xb1}, {0x5b}, {0x6a}, {0xcb}, {0xbe}, {0x39}, {0x4a}, {0x4c}, {0x58}, {0xcf}, //5
            {0xd0}, {0xef}, {0xaa}, {0xfb}, {0x43}, {0x4d}, {0x33}, {0x85}, {0x45}, {0xf9}, {0x02}, {0x7f}, {0x50}, {0x3c}, {0x9f}, {0xa8}, //6
            {0x51}, {0xa3}, {0x40}, {0x8f}, {0x92}, {0x9d}, {0x38}, {0xf5}, {0xbc}, {0xb6}, {0xda}, {0x21}, {0x10}, {0xff}, {0xf3}, {0xd2}, //7
            {0xcd}, {0x0c}, {0x13}, {0xec}, {0x5f}, {0x97}, {0x44}, {0x17}, {0xc4}, {0xa7}, {0x7e}, {0x3d}, {0x64}, {0x5d}, {0x19}, {0x73}, //8
            {0x60}, {0x81}, {0x4f}, {0xdc}, {0x22}, {0x2a}, {0x90}, {0x88}, {0x46}, {0xee}, {0xb8}, {0x14}, {0xde}, {0x5e}, {0x0b}, {0xdb}, //9
            {0xe0}, {0x32}, {0x3a}, {0x0a}, {0x49}, {0x06}, {0x24}, {0x5c}, {0xc2}, {0xd3}, {0xac}, {0x62}, {0x91}, {0x95}, {0xe4}, {0x79}, //A
            {0xe7}, {0xc8}, {0x37}, {0x6d}, {0x8d}, {0xd5}, {0x4e}, {0xa9}, {0x6c}, {0x56}, {0xf4}, {0xea}, {0x65}, {0x7a}, {0xae}, {0x08}, //B
            {0xba}, {0x78}, {0x25}, {0x2e}, {0x1c}, {0xa6}, {0xb4}, {0xc6}, {0xe8}, {0xdd}, {0x74}, {0x1f}, {0x4b}, {0xbd}, {0x8b}, {0x8a}, //C
            {0x70}, {0x3e}, {0xb5}, {0x66}, {0x48}, {0x03}, {0xf6}, {0x0e}, {0x61}, {0x35}, {0x57}, {0xb9}, {0x86}, {0xc1}, {0x1d}, {0x9e}, //D
            {0xe1}, {0xf8}, {0x98}, {0x11}, {0x69}, {0xd9}, {0x8e}, {0x94}, {0x9b}, {0x1e}, {0x87}, {0xe9}, {0xce}, {0x55}, {0x28}, {0xdf}, //E
            {0x8c}, {0xa1}, {0x89}, {0x0d}, {0xbf}, {0xe6}, {0x42}, {0x68}, {0x41}, {0x99}, {0x2d}, {0x0f}, {0xb0}, {0x54}, {0xbb}, {0x16}  //F
            };
```

What goes wrong in here?

Comment: That's an `int[256, 1]`. You should only have inner curly braces around every 16, not each one.

Comment: What you have here is just a 1 dimensional array with 256 objects. `new int[16, 16]` means you need 16 arrays each of those having 16 objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make a matrix of 16 rows and 16 columns.

you can try to use `{}` contain 16 int then make 16 columns.

```
int[,] SBox = new int[16, 16]
    {

        {0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76} , //0
        {0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0}, //1
        {0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15}, //2
        {0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75}, //3
        {0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84}, //4
        {0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf}, //5
        {0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8}, //6
        {0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2}, //7
        {0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73}, //8
        {0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb}, //9
        {0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79}, //A
        {0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08}, //B
        {0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a}, //C
        {0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e}, //D
        {0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf}, //E
        {0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16}  //F
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your array definition is only up to 16 items, but you are assigning an array containing 256 items.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/

A multi dimensional array must be declared and assigned as below:

> // Declare and set array element values
>   int[,] multiDimensionalArray2 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };